# POST request with axios gets treated as GET nuxt to Laravel

Tags: laravel, post, request, axios, nuxt.js

[image]I'm making a request to my laravel backend.
But the request gets treated as a GET instead of a POST, I can't find that the problem is..

here is the function:

```
    this.$axios
    .post('/create_car', {
      data: formData
    })
    .then(res => {
      this.status = true
      this.isCreatingCar = false
    })
```

and trying to recieve it in this controller function:

```
public function createCar(Request $request) {

    $title = $request->title;
    $previewText = $request->previewText;
    $fuel = $request->fuel;
    $gearbox = $request->gearbox;
    $brand = $request->brand;
    $model = $request->model;
    $year = $request->year;
    $miles = $request->miles;
    $price = $request->price;
    $carType = $request->carType;
    $images = $request->images;

    $car = Car::create([
        'title' => $title,
        'previewText' => $previewText,
        'fuel' => $fuel,
        'gearbox' => $gearbox,
        'brand' => $brand,
        'model' => $model,
        'year' => $year,
        'miles' => $miles,
        'price' => $price,
        'carType' => $carType
    ]);

    // store each image
    foreach($images as $image) {
        $imagePath = Storage::disk('uploads')->put('/cars' . '/' . $car->id, $image);
        carImage::create([
            'carImageCaption' => $title,
            'carImagePath' => 'uploads' . $imagePath,
            'carId' => $car->id
        ]);
    }

    return response()->json(['errors' => false, 'data' => $car]);
}
```

here is the route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'throttle:20.5'], function () {
    Route::post('/create_car', 'CarController@createCar');
});
```

in the xamp log it seems like it sends two request first a POST and then a GET 3 seconds apart

Comment: Can you post or make an image of the full error message

Comment: Added the picture

Comment: Ok where is this route located at is it inside the web.php or api.php, are you further 100% sure that it is due to calling create_car?

Comment: Ive been sending other requests to the api, its under api.php, almost 100% since my other requests are working

Answer (score 0):

Ok to fix this you need to call the route properly, since the route inside your `api.php` call it like this:

```
this.$axios
.post('/api/create_car', {
  data: formData
})
.then(res => {
  this.status = true
  this.isCreatingCar = false
})
```

Comment: actually i have that in my "baseURL" in nuxt.config.
axios: {

    baseURL: 'http://dev.localhost/bil2000-api/public/api/'
  },

Comment: Did you try it this way?

Comment: Yes, then i got a 404